# how would i change post->ID to work correctly when querying pages?

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails, id

i am building the following script to query data from every child page of a certain page. i have it working fine, but i am unable to get the featured image, because i am using `$post->ID`. what would i change `$post->ID` to be in order to work correctly with the rest of my function? any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => 91,
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );

    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) :

        echo '<div class="events_lists_on_page">';

        while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();

             //grab the menu item data
             $image_uploaded_meta_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_listing_image_id', true);
             $image_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_uploaded_meta_id, 'full');

             //grab and save title of post
             $title = get_the_title();

             //grab and save the link to the post
             $link = get_permalink();

             //grab content
             $the_content = get_the_content();

             echo '<div class="element">';

             echo '<img src="'. $image_thumb_url[0] .'">';

             echo '<div class="text"><p>' . $title .'</p></div>';

             echo '<p>'. $the_content .'</p>';

             echo '</div>';

        endwhile;

        echo '</div>';
    endif;
```

Comment: Are you using custom field or any other custom meta box to insert attachment image id??

Comment: You could just leave it empty in the loop, like `get_post_meta('', '_listing_image_id', true)`. This worked for me when trying to get featured image's URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `get_the_ID()`

```
$image_uploaded_meta_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_listing_image_id', true);
```

`get_the_ID()` is a core Wordpress function that acts directly inside the Wordpress Loop, retrieving the id of the current item being loaded. `$post->id` is not working because the variable `$post` has no scope inside the loop.

Here's the link to the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: this worked great - but yes i would like to know WHY this is working. if you could help explain that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Define **global $post** when **while loop start*** like that below

```
        while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();global $post;
```